# Change/Update Card without interruption of current billing cycle

Tags: payment-gateway, stripe-payments

I had a requirement that if customer **update/change** their **credit card** then is there any way exist in `Stripe API` to retain the existing billing cycle?

Any thoughts will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the customer's card entirely, you would update the *customer*, not their card, using the [customer update API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer). You'd have a form in your application that uses `stripe.js` to generate a new card token, just like on signup, and then pass that to the customer update API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can Please Ref url [https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#update_card](https://stripe.com/docs/api/java#update%5fcard)

Upgrade card api will not change the current billing cycle of the customer plan.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have used the above link but it only updates the billing address and expiry date of the card , but I need to change card itself and want to retain the existing billing cycle.